# How to extract string using RE in python?

Tags: python, regex

this is a string:

```
'ObjectId("5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55")'
```

I want to get "`5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55`",How do I use the regex?

Comment: That’s a data type and what have you tried to get the id? Do you expect us to do it for you?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Why can't you just slice off the parentheses? You  don't need regex

Comment: This is a string in json, I just want to get the value inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a crazy question but why not

```
>>> myval = 'ObjectId("5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55")'
>>> myval.split("(")[1]
'"5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55")'
>>> myval.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
'"5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55"'
>>> import re

>>> re.findall('[a-zA-z0-9]', myval.split("(")[1].split(")")[0])
['5', 'a', '6', '0', 'a', '3', '9', '4', 'a', 'c', '7', '3', 'c', '2', '3', '3', 'b', 'a', '1', 'a', 'c', 'c', '5', '5']

>>> "".join(re.findall('[a-zA-z0-9]', myval.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]))
'5a60a394ac73c233ba1acc55'
```